# A book which can effectively bridge the gap between High School and the Olympiads.

Tags: contest-math, book-recommendation

I know that this question may be weird or ridiculous to some but—
**Can anyone suggest me a book which can effectively bridge the gap between High School and the Olympiads?**

I have done *"Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight"* and doing *"Higher Algebra by Bernard and Child"*. Both of these books are really good and give clear cut theory and start with the basic problems all the way to the difficult ones (for me) thought they lack solved examples.

I want a book like the above two which would cover all the areas of mathematics required for Olympiads, give all the required theory in short with proofs and has decent amount of solved and unsolved problems ranging from *basic* to the *Olympiad* level.

Also, try not to recommend me the book which would present basic and obvious solved examples and then proceed to give the most difficult problems it would find.
In short, I wouldn't prefer a book in which the difference in the difficulty between the examples and problems is too much.

**Essentially, I want a book which would start with basic theory and basic problems and take them all the way to the Olympiad level.**

Comment: I bet there *are* books that cram on skills needed for Olympiads, if you just search for them.  That seems to be the central question. I think many people are going to be tempted to reply with their favorite subject-based recommendation, which I don't think would answer the question.  The idea of "olympiad-centric royal road to mathematics" seems off-topic, and more importantly a pretty lame way to study mathematics.  If not off-topic, this question is way too broad.

Comment: @rschwieb everyone doesn't has that much of time to read through the countless examples and relations a book tries to give as an "introduction" and then think for days for the possible solution to a difficult problem which could've been made simpler by giving a similar example before or atleast by giving a solution at the back.

Comment: @rschwieb I've given enough of detalis. So far, I've liked the "Hall and Knight" and "Bernard and Child" way of books and wanted a similar kind of book.

Comment: Perhaps A. Gardiner, [The Mathematical Olympiad Handbook](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0198501056)?

Comment: I hate to break you the news, but to me this sounds a bit like asking for *one exercise program to bridge the gap between normal high school physical education (done well), and the student athletes competing for NCAA scholarships*. Yes, studying math books will help. But, the most important things is that you have to work on your problem solving skills. Really hard. Not unlike those student athletes (who also spend many hours at the gym and whatnot - in spite of their talent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a couple of decades [**Problem-Solving Strategies**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387982191) by Arthur Engel has been one of the most highly recommended books.

Lesser known, but perhaps also very appropriate for what you want (because they have lots of short "theory" sections motivated by some of the problems), is the 2-volume [**Hungarian Problem Book I**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883856115) and [**Hungarian Problem Book II**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883856123). Despite dating from 1894-1905 (I) and 1906-1928 (II), the problems and theory discussions are still very appropriate for present-day contests.

Over 100 books, along with informative reviews by mathematics professionals (whatever that means), can be found in MAA's book list under the category [Problems Olympiad Level](https://www.maa.org/tags/problems-olympiad-level). Also, there are the books listed at [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/list/other-products) (which seems more limited than it used to be, but maybe my memory is off).